# Fastest PHP template engine (or framework) supporting inheritance for multiple sites

Tags: php, frameworks, template-engine

I need to find a template engine and/or a framework in PHP that lets me publish a website with one template, and reuse the template on other websites on the same server by making a child template, where I only override certain design elements from the parent template.

What I am looking for is speed of deployment - which template engine (PHP required) can I use to get the additional sites out there, the fastest?

As an example, I have websites to launch for various markets, in different categories. So I would create a UK site template that is the master template, then override details like the logo and static texts for the Swedish and French markets. Additionally, for different categories (such as Men's Fashion vs. Women's Fashion) I would need to override the images and colors of certain design elements (like pictures on the front page, and so on).

All of the sites I need to launch are based on the same API (RESTful JSON), and I need to be able to easily integrate a form for searching, sorting and filtering - so the template engine would have to allow for easy integration with variables...

Which solution would you suggest fit these requirements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also look at [Twig](http://www.twig-project.org/). Here is some more info on it and how it compares to the others: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/34/templating-engines-in-php

Comment: This is a great comparison - and answers the doubt about Smarty that I had about inheritance. Twig actually fits this solution the best.

Answer (score 3):

Simple -> [Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/)

Uses a very simple templating engine - and easy to learn as their documentation is so amazing

Answer (score 1):

Hrm. Set up codeigniter 2 with packages and the template library 'extension', put the template files in a separate repository and load them up as a package for each 'child site'. If you define your regions carefully that should be all you need to do :)

Comment: I already have a CI 2 installation on one site - could you give me a link to more information about this?

Comment: I guess you're referring to this Template Library --> [link](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/)

Comment: Yeup! Thats the one. Look in config/autoload.php for packages :)

Answer (score 1):

If not a framework but a template engine I can't think of anything else than using [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net) for templating. It's easy to use and very flexible. You can create a main template e.g. `main.tpl` put in some variables and re-use that template over and over by just assigning needed values for each site e.g. index.php (for some site):

```
$smarty->assign(array(
   'PageTitle' => 'Some site title'
   'CustomContent' => $smarty->fetch('custom.tpl'); // custom for this site
));

// of course you've setup the template location at this point
$MainTemplate = $smarty->fetch('main.tpl');

$smarty->display($MainTemplate);
```

On `main.tpl` you'd have something like:

```
// on main.tpl you'd have
<title>{$PageTitle}</title>
......
<body>
{$CustomContent}
</body>
```

Just an idea :)

Comment: From what I know there is no built-in json handler in Smarty, however, it does support extensions such as the smarty {json} extension. http://jlix.net/extensions/smarty/json

Comment: Thanks - another question, if you're familiar with Smarty - how does it handle translation of content into multiple languages?

Comment: Based on using it I'd say it handles it pretty well. I've worked on sites with different languages (japanese, chinese, russian, korean, etc) although the contents are of course coming from our database and only feeding it to Smarty, it still renders the strings with no issues. If you're using PHP `gettext` there is a plugin in Smarty that let's you use it e.g. `{t}Term{/t}` which would be translated based on your current PHP locale.

Comment: Great! I'll give Smarty a try.

Comment: CI already has support for smarty... what on earth are you guys on about? JSON support? Language support? It's a *templating* language, a way to abstract away from your server side code language and it most definitely doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: @SkippyChalmers, what are you on about? he asked `template engine (or framework)` and `which template engine (PHP required) can I use to get the additional sites out there, the fastest?`, answer is provided. of course it doesnt support json but you can handle such needs with it. did someone mentioned language support? of course smarty can handle translated content if you feed it right.

Comment: @tradyblix oh my. What on earth? Of **course** smarty can handle different languages. Like you yourself said, it's a *templating* language. You know what? PHP can be used as a templating language too. How do you plan to "configure" smarty to have JSON support? Why does smarty need JSON support if it's being run from a PHP script? The OP's question was: "publish a website with one template, and reuse the template on other websites on the same server by making a child template" which I don't think can be answered by just saying "use smarty". Which is just like saying: "use PHP".

Comment: @SkippyChalmers, @tradyblix Just to clarify, the point to my question was about the fastest way I can go from template one to template two (...or ten), in terms of deployment, on multiple sites with much the same functionality. Both a Smarty, CI+Template, and CI+Smarty solution would be acceptable answers for me, if I can write less code to integrate with my JSON responses. (The translation question was not directly related to the question and didn't affect my choice of best answer)

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework and setting up different 'sites' as modules would probably be a good approach if they share a lot of logic etc. Each module could have a unique layout.

Zend Framework allows you to work using the MVC pattern and makes it easy to separate logic and presentation. You can find more information at http://framework.zend.com/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest http://agiletoolkit.org/ for the following reasons:

- built-in and integrated component-level templates. CSS framework is based on jQuery UI CSS and 960.gs. Most frameworks handle templates on page-level, which makes them less re-usable.
- out-of-the-box forms with ajax support, filters in different shapes and html/css layouts. UI components work with MVC or static array data (which is easy to use with JSON). Most framework do not supply form HTML. Also generators typically would integrate ui elements with models only.
- object-oriented component approach constructs site from "views objects" which you can share between multiple sites and merge with different models. Pages are also defined as classes. That means you can have 2 pages with common ancestor and minor changes. If you know OOP it becomes a powerful feature. Most frameworks would require separate installation and sharing components is more difficult. Also most frameworks would require a separate template per page.
- solution is much more lightweight, geared towards efficient development and integration. In comparison, zend focuses on component independence. Light footprint, and faster speed is direct result of this.

Agile Toolkit is open source.

I hope this information could bring some fresh insight and see development from different perspective. I actively work with the framework, documentation is in-complete at this time and under construction, but the architecture is very promising and requires to know only some PHP and object-oriented programming skills.

Comment: The Agile Toolkit really does look promising - although a need something with a stable and proven track record, I will give the atk4 a try. Looking forward to additional documentation, especially about how to get started and tutorials.

Comment: http://new.agiletoolkit.org/?page=learn/tutorial/jobeet would be a good start for now. Working very hard on everything else. I know it needs work, and appreciate anyone trying it.